# Reuse io.Reader and capture length

Tags: memory, go, garbage-collection

I'm consuming a remote API which returns an `io.ReadCloser` (so no way of getting the length without a read) and need to add a header to the response that includes the data length from the original `io.Reader`, then write the resulting `io.Reader` to an `io.Writer`.

Except for the omission of error-handling, the following functions are functionally correct.  The `addHeaderBytesBuffer` function however, results in 7 allocations and the `addHeaderTeeReader` function results in 8:

```
func addHeaderBytesBuffer(in io.Reader) (out io.Reader) {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    io.Copy(buf, in)

    header := createHeader(buf.Len())
    return io.MultiReader(header, buf)
}

func addHeaderTeeReader(in io.Reader) (out io.Reader) {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    n, _ := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, io.TeeReader(in, buf))

    return io.MultiReader(createHeader(int(n)), buf)
}

func createHeader(length int) (out io.Reader) {
    return strings.NewReader(fmt.Sprintf("HEADER:%d", length))
}
```

I'm maintaining a `sync.Pool` of `bytes.Buffer` instances to re-use to reduce GC pressure but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Try creating a buffer with big capacity, so no reallocation is needed. See [`bytes.NewBuffer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer). Also don't forget to call [`Buffer.Reset()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Reset) when you're done with it.

Comment: I've created wrapper methods for `sync.Pool` to make sure the buffer is reset yeah :)  Unfortunately the required buffer size is going to range wildly, so deciding on an arbitrarily large buffer (and even preventing huge buffers from re-entering the pool) is still going to present quite a job for the GC.

Comment: Dealing with many allocations, or large allocations, will present more work for the GC - there is no way around that. I would spike a couple of tests with various initial and maximum buffer sizes, and see what performs best in practice with realistic test data.